# How do I get Active Directory groups when already authenticated through ldap Spring 3.0?

Tags: java, active-directory, spring-security, ldap

I am building on top of some already developed code and have been asked to authenticate through ldap which I can do but Now I have been asked to set permissions based on Active Directory groups. The Issue is I am unsure how to take what I have and build upon it. I'm not experienced in Spring at all and I have tried to (but with no success) start from scratch with Active Directory using a few tutorials including [this][1] and I have looked for help [here][2] and [here][3] but with no success. Firstly I cannot use spring 3.1, we can only use 3.0, and I have been unsuccessful in adapting any of the examples I have mentioned above.

Is there a way I can get Active directory Groups (and other attributes) from what I have already?
Here is what I have done so far:

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/images/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/css/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('CUSTOMADMIN')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>
    <ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="ldap://url:portnumber/ou=People,dc=abc,dc=com" manager-dn="dn" manager-password="password" />
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapServer" />
                <beans:property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:value>uid={0}</beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="com.company.group.appname.ldap.RolesPopulator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="userRoleService" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>            
</beans:beans>
```

**RolesPopulator.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapAuthoritiesPopulator;

import com.company.group.appname.service.IUserRoleService;

public class RolesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator 
{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RolesPopulator.class);
    @Autowired
    private IUserRoleService userRoleService;

    public RolesPopulator(IUserRoleService userRoleService)
    {
       this.userRoleService = userRoleService;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username) 
    {
        List<GrantedAuthority> userPerms = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        log.debug("UserPermsions: "+userPerms.toString());

        //get users permissions from service
        List<String> userRoles = userRoleService.getPermissions(username);
        for (String string : userRoles) 
        {
            userPerms.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(string));
        }

        return userPerms;
    }

}
```

**UserRoleServiceImpl.java** (implementation of IUserRoleService)

```
package com.company.group.appname.service.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.company.group.appname.service.IUserRoleService;

@Service("userRoleService")
public class UserRoleServiceImpl implements IUserRoleService {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserRoleServiceImpl.class);

    public List<String> getPermissions(String username) {


        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
        roles.add("CUSTOMADMIN");
        return roles;
    }

}
```

This all Authenticates fine but I have no comprehension of how to get the Active directory groups from here. What I want to be able to do is from the `getPermissions(username)` method I want to be able to get a list of groups associated with the username from Active Directory and if it contains a particular group name then return the role else return null (or some other role).

I'll be honest and say I have looked at a lot of code examples that do the Authentication through Active directory and can get the groups then but I have never gotten any of them to work (most of examples I found could fix there issues with spring security 3.1, this is not an option unfortunately) And I have not found an example that approaches it this way either.

Any Guidance or help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really can't upgrade from 3.0, why don't you just copy the [ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java) class from 3.1 into your codebase and use that? It loads the user authorities from the `memberOf` attribute in the AD user entry.

Upgrading from 3.0 to 3.1 should be relatively painless, but if you can't there's nothing to stop you using an individual class as part of your own build. Then you wouldn't need the `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` code you've written (which isn't a very good fit for AD anyway).